# .net core packages and dependency to the .net runtimes

Tags: .net-core, nuget

Assuming I'm already using the NuGet Package

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components 5.0.3
```

Can I upgrade it to `5.0.5` without having the `5.0.5` runtime installed (`dotnet --list-runtimes`)?

If I look at the dependencies in Nuget it just states:

```
net5.0 (no specific sdk, nor runtime)
 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Analyzers (>= 5.0.5)
 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization (>= 5.0.5)
```

Comment: It really depends on if the .NET5 packages depend on anything in the .NET5 runtime. Sometimes they do, sometimes they don't. I had an azure function compiled against the .NET5 runtime, deployed it out to a server. It worked fine. I started adding features then I deployed it. It failed on the Azure server. Turns out I had .NET5 runtime installed, but the server didn't. I couldn't figure out what was going on until I saw the Azure server only had 3.1 installed. I rolled packages back to 3.1 and everything was fine. So I try to stick to what the target environment is capable of because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason to upgrade to 5.0.5 from 5.0.3? If its because you need something specific added in 5.0.5, then, while it *might* work, chances are it wont, as Andy says